# Help deciphering meaning/conjugation of 言っちゃいとっちゃいます

Tags: grammar, conjugations

I was watching Sword Art Online with the help of a transcript of the episode. There was one word I didn't catch while listening, and when I looked it up, it was 言っちゃいとっちゃいます. I honestly have no idea what this is composed of or what meaning is implied to 言う here.

Context:

> 今日のMMOストリームでは世界中の大注目ソードアート·オンライン、略してSAOって**言っちゃいとっちゃいまーす**

I'm guessing 言っちゃい is just 言ってしまう, but after that I really have no idea.

Comment: Is that an official transcript? I can't honestly tell what the announcer is saying when Kirito turns the page of the magazine. Anyway 〜ちゃい could be the continuative form of 〜ちゃう (〜てしまう) like you guessed

Comment: I don't believe it is official. It could very well be just be a typo/mishearing on the transcriber's part.

Comment: Well better wait for the Japanese to wake up then but my guess is that the announcer just emphasizes that she makes the abbreviation up on the fly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「言っちゃいとっちゃいまーす」 makes no sense.  That is unless there was a dialect in which it made sense.  All I can guarantee is that it makes absolutely no sense in Standard Japanese.

If what you watched, however, is the video below and you are referring to the sentence starting around 0:36, then it says something COMPLETELY different.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCMjET7fC9w

The girl says:

> 「今日のMMOストリームでは、世界中が大注目、ソードアート・オンライン、略してSAO を**ピックアップしちゃいまーす**。」

Comment: That makes much more sense. Btw, do any of [these streaming services linked in meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/765/1272) provide Japanese subtitles for shows that are already in Japanese or is it even a common practice?

Comment: @siikamiika You can't expect much. If anything, Japanese digital broadcasting contains subtitles data for the aurally impaired, but not for all programs. Much less I know how to rip them out :P